# How can I draw multiple circles in my canvas?

Tags: java, android, canvas, paint

I can draw one circle but my problem is to know how can I draw multiple circles every time I clicked.
The center of the circle has to be the X and the Y coordinates that are clicked and I need to store that point on my Vector, and the vector cannot be destroyed everytime I click the View.
If I don't have the invalidate on the end of **if (figure == 1)** it doesn't draw the circle at all.
My center is a Point2D which has int x, int y stored.

```
package com.example.soalr.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

import java.util.Vector;


public class MyView extends View {
    Paint paint = null;
    int figure;
    int lados_poly;
    int cor;
    int deletar;
    Circulo cir;
    Circulo raio;
    int CursorX, CursorY;
    int nrCliques;
    Vector<Ponto2D> ptsCirc = new Vector<Ponto2D>();

    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        paint = new Paint();
        figure = 0;
        cor = 0;
    }

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
        figure = 0;
        cor = 0;

        Ponto2D centroCirc = new Ponto2D();
        centroCirc.x = CursorX;
        centroCirc.y = CursorY;
        cir = new Circulo(centroCirc);
    }

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        paint = new Paint();
        figure = 0;
        cor = 0;

    }


    public void clickEcra() {
        setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        nrCliques++;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                        CursorX = (int)event.getX();
                        CursorY = (int)event.getY();

                        if (figure == 1) {
                            Ponto2D centroCirc = new Ponto2D();
                            centroCirc.x = CursorX;
                            centroCirc.y = CursorY;
                            ptsCirc.add(centroCirc);
                            invalidate();
                        }

                    default:
                        return false;
                }
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        clickEcra();

        Ponto2D p3 = new Ponto2D();
        p3.x = 600;
        p3.y = 150;

        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#F5F1E0"));
        canvas.drawPaint(paint);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#3F5866"));

        //cores
        if (cor == 1) {
            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#393E46"));
        } else if (cor == 2){
            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#00ADB5"));
        } else if (cor == 3) {
            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#F8B500"));
        } else if (cor == 4) {
            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FC3C3C"));
        }


        //figuras

        if (figure == 1) {

            if (ptsCirc.size() > 0) {
                for (int a = 0; a <= ptsCirc.size(); a++) {
                    Circulo raio = new Circulo(ptsCirc.get(a));
                    raio.radius = 100;
                    canvas.drawCircle(ptsCirc.get(a).x, ptsCirc.get(a).y, raio.radius, paint);
                }
            }
        }

       else if (figure == 2) {
            clickEcra();
            Ponto2D p1 = new Ponto2D();
            Ponto2D p2 = new Ponto2D();

            Reta retinha = new Reta(p1, p2);

            if (nrCliques == 1) {
                p1.x = CursorX;
                p1.y = CursorY;
                System.out.println("x1: " + p1.x + " y1: " + p1.y);
            } else if (nrCliques == 2) {
                p2.x = CursorX;
                p2.y = CursorY;
                System.out.println("x2: " + p2.x + " y2: " + p2.y);
            }

            System.out.println("x2_: " + retinha.pfinal.x + " y2_: " + retinha.pfinal.y);
            System.out.println("x1_: " + retinha.pinicial.x + " y1_: " + retinha.pinicial.y);
            canvas.drawLine(retinha.pinicial.x, retinha.pinicial.y, retinha.pfinal.x, retinha.pfinal.y, paint);
        } else if (figure == 3) {
            Poligono poly = new Poligono(lados_poly);

            if (lados_poly >= 3) {
                for (int i = 0; i <= lados_poly - 1; i++) {
                    Ponto2D ponto4 = new Ponto2D(poly.pontosPolig.get(i).x, poly.pontosPolig.get(i).y);
                    Ponto2D ponto5 = new Ponto2D();

                    if (i < lados_poly) {
                        ponto5.x = poly.pontosPolig.get(i + 1).x;
                        ponto5.y = poly.pontosPolig.get(i + 1).y;

                        Reta retaPoli = new Reta(ponto4, ponto5);
                        int var_lados = lados_poly - 1;

                        if (i != var_lados) {
                            canvas.drawLine(retaPoli.pinicial.x, retaPoli.pinicial.y, retaPoli.pfinal.x, retaPoli.pfinal.y, paint);
                        } else {
                            canvas.drawLine(poly.pontosPolig.firstElement().x, poly.pontosPolig.firstElement().y, retaPoli.pinicial.x, retaPoli.pinicial.y, paint);
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (deletar == 2){
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#F5F1E0"));
            canvas.drawPaint(paint);
            nrCliques = 0;
        }
    }




    public void setfigure(int a) {
        this.figure = a;
    }

    public void Cor1_mudar(int text_cor) {
        this.cor = text_cor;
    }

    public void verLados (int lados){
        this.lados_poly = lados;
    }

    public void Resetar(int delete){
        this.deletar = delete;
    }
}
```

This is Circle.java:
package com.example.soalr.myapplication;

```
public class Circulo {
    int radius;
    Ponto2D centro;


    public Circulo(Ponto2D c) {
        radius = 0;
        centro = c;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems here:

1. You only see 1 circle. This is probably because `nrCliques` is not the value you expect. Instead of iterating from 0 to `nrCliques`, consider iterating from 0 to `ptsCirc.size()`, or using a [for..each](https://www.javatpoint.com/for-each-loop) loop. For problems like this, [the debugger is your friend](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/).
2. You don't see any circles unless you have that `invalidate()` call in `onDraw()`. Calling `invalidate()` from `onDraw()` causes the framework to call `onDraw()` repeatedly, as fast as it can. This doesn't hurt anything but it uses a lot of processor power for no good reason. It's better to "cue" your `View` to redraw at the moment that its attendant data changes. In this case, this means putting the `invalidate()` call after that call to `ptsCirc.add()`. Then, you'll only get roughly 1 call to `onDraw()` each time you tap the screen.

Comment: That means putting the invalidate inside the function of click? @greeble31

Comment: The application stops. I'll update the code, hope u see it @greeble31

Comment: @soalribeiro What is the exception in logcat? Please add this to your question.

Answer (score 0):

This is working code, the problem was I wasn't verifying if the Vector had anything inside him.

```
public class MyView extends View {
    Paint paint = null;
    int figure;
    int lados_poly;
    int cor;
    int deletar;
    int CursorX, CursorY;
    int nrCliques;
    Vector<Ponto2D> ptsCirc = new Vector<Ponto2D>();

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        paint = new Paint();
        figure = 0;
        cor = 0;
    }

    public void clickEcra() {
        setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                        CursorX = (int)event.getX();
                        CursorY = (int)event.getY();

                        if (figure == 1) {
                            Ponto2D centroCirc = new Ponto2D();
                            centroCirc.x = CursorX;
                            centroCirc.y = CursorY;
                            ptsCirc.add(centroCirc);
                            invalidate();
                        }

                    default:
                        return false;
                }
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        clickEcra();

        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#F5F1E0"));
        canvas.drawPaint(paint);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#3F5866"));

        //cores
        if (cor == 1) {
            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#393E46"));
        } else if (cor == 2){
            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#00ADB5"));
        } else if (cor == 3) {
            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#F8B500"));
        } else if (cor == 4) {
            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FC3C3C"));
        }


        //figuras
        if (figure == 1) {
            if (ptsCirc.size() > 0) {
                for (int a = 0; a < ptsCirc.size(); a++) {
                    Circulo raio = new Circulo(ptsCirc.get(a));
                    raio.radius = 100;
                    canvas.drawCircle(ptsCirc.get(a).x, ptsCirc.get(a).y, raio.radius, paint);
                }
            }
        }

        if (deletar == 2){
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#F5F1E0"));
            canvas.drawPaint(paint);
            nrCliques = 0;
            ptsCirc.removeAllElements();
            ptsReta.removeAllElements();
        }
    }




    public void setfigure(int a) {
        this.figure = a;
    }

    public void Cor1_mudar(int text_cor) {
        this.cor = text_cor;
    }

    public void Resetar(int delete){
        this.deletar = delete;
    }
}
```